# Connecting the MKR GPS shield by cable or as a shield

Tags: gps, mkr1010

I have an MKR WiFi 1010 and an MKR GPS Shield. When I connect my GPS Shield using the I2C cable, it works fine.

This works perfectly (the bottom is the MKR Motor Carrier):

[image]

However, when I use it as a shield (hat?) using the pins, it doesn't.

This doesn't work. The code blocks somewhere (I suspect `GPS.available()`):

[image]

My question, should it work the same whether it is cabled or put on with the pins? Or should I change my code somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the shop page](https://store.arduino.cc/collections/shields/products/arduino-mkr-gps-shield):

> It interfaces with Arduino boards either through a serial interface, when used with headers and put on top of a MKR board, or through an I2C interface and a dedicated ESLOV cable supplied as bundle.

From Arduino_MKRGPS library [reference](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/arduino_mkrgps/begin/):

`begin()` Parameters:

- GPS_MODE_I2C to use the MKR GPS with the I2C cable (default setting),
- GPS_MODE_SHIELD if using the MKR GPS as a shield.